# Is it possible to get i18n translation source file from firebase?

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, vue-i18n

Is it possible to modify vue-i18n so translation single JSON file with 2 different language inside and which come form Firebase will render text dynamically to vue template

I used mounted function with axios to get data form firebase. But I have no clue how i18n should treat this as a source file for a translation.

Basically I put my two translation source files from locales folder to the one United.json and I uploaded this to firebase, now I want to load this back to my app form there (firebase) but I see no solution there how to set locale so that it will render and translate all the `{{ $t(example.locale) }}` and I should be able to be bind it as this  `v-bind:src="$t('products.'+ index +'.options.'+ i +'.image')"`

```
//main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import i18n from './i18n'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

let language = to.params.lang;
  if (!language) {
    language = 'ee'
  }

  i18n.locale = language
  next()
}); 

new Vue({
  router,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return{
        localekk : ''
    }

  }
,
   methods: {
    setLocale(lang) {
      Vue.$i18n.locale = lang;
    }
  }, 
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://example.firebaseio.com/locales.json')
        .then(response => {
            this.locale = response.data;
            console.log(response)


        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

  }
}).$mount('#app')




//i18n.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'



Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i) // may by to change './locales' but again - how?
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'ee',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'ee',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
  silentTranslationWarn: true,

})
```

Comment: Looks nice. Got anywhere with that?